# How to return the correct months?

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

First date should be `28/03/2017` but it's returning as `28/02/2017`.

The months after the first date seems to be correct.

Is there a better way of doing this or can someone help me figure out why the first date is acting like it is?

```js
var date = new Date("Tue Mar 28 2017 13:14:00 GMT+0100 (BST)");
var additionalMonth = date.getMonth();

function addZero(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}

function formatDateToString(d){
    var month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1);
    var day = '' + d.getDate();
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var hour = d.getHours();
    var minute = d.getMinutes();
    var second = d.getSeconds();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
    hour = addZero(hour);
    minute = addZero(minute);
 second = addZero(second);
 
 var date = [day, month, year].join('/');
 var time = [hour, minute, second].join(':');
 
 var newDate = date + " " + time;
 return newDate;
}

function setTimeForDate(date){
 date.setHours(12);
 date.setMinutes(0);
 date.setSeconds(0);
 return date;
}

function calculateDate(date, month){
 date.setMonth(month);
 date = setTimeForDate(date);
 return date;
}

function calculateLastDayMonth(date, day){
 var month = date.getMonth();
 var year = date.getFullYear();
 var d = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
 if(day >= d){
  date = new Date(year, month, 0);
 }
 date = setTimeForDate(date);
 return date;
}

function returnFormattedDate(startDate, additionalMonth){
 var day = startDate.getDate();
 var newDate = calculateDate(startDate, additionalMonth);
 var correctDate = calculateLastDayMonth(newDate, day);
 return formatDateToString(correctDate);
}

$(".returnedDate").text("START DATE: " + returnFormattedDate(date, additionalMonth));

for(var x = 0; x <= 5; x++){
  $("body").append(returnFormattedDate(date, additionalMonth) + "<br>");
  additionalMonth++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5 class="returnedDate"></h5>
```

Comment: My first advice would be to use momentjs, that makes handling dates easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change `var month = date.getMonth();` `to var month = date.getMonth()+1;` because the index starts from `0`.

```js
var date = new Date("Tue Mar 28 2017 13:14:00 GMT+0100 (BST)");
var additionalMonth = date.getMonth();

function addZero(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}

function formatDateToString(d){
    var month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1);
    var day = '' + d.getDate();
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var hour = d.getHours();
    var minute = d.getMinutes();
    var second = d.getSeconds();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
    hour = addZero(hour);
    minute = addZero(minute);
 second = addZero(second);
 
 var date = [day, month, year].join('/');
 var time = [hour, minute, second].join(':');
 
 var newDate = date + " " + time;
 return newDate;
}

function setTimeForDate(date){
 date.setHours(12);
 date.setMinutes(0);
 date.setSeconds(0);
 return date;
}

function calculateDate(date, month){
 date.setMonth(month);
 date = setTimeForDate(date);
 return date;
}

function calculateLastDayMonth(date, day){
 var month = date.getMonth()+1;
 var year = date.getFullYear();
 var d = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
 if(day >= d){
  date = new Date(year, month, 0);
 }
 date = setTimeForDate(date);
 return date;
}

function returnFormattedDate(startDate, additionalMonth){
 var day = startDate.getDate();
 var newDate = calculateDate(startDate, additionalMonth);
 var correctDate = calculateLastDayMonth(newDate, day);
 return formatDateToString(correctDate);
}

$(".returnedDate").text("START DATE: " + returnFormattedDate(date, additionalMonth));

for(var x = 0; x <= 5; x++){
  $("body").append(returnFormattedDate(date, additionalMonth) + "<br>");
  additionalMonth++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5 class="returnedDate"></h5>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 different approaches:

```
var additionalMonth = date.getMonth();
```

and

```
var month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1);
```

JS returns months counting from `0`, so for January it's `0`, `1` for February, etc., so if you want proper number you need to add `1`, as you do for `month`. You can check this out [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
```

You should add 1 to the month because the month indexing starts with 0;

Answer (score 1):

Please change the line in calculateLastDayMonth() function.
var month = date.getMonth()+1; i.e you need to add +1 it works fine

Please find the updated code mentioned below:

```js
var date = new Date("Tue Mar 28 2017 13:14:00 GMT+0100 (BST)");
var additionalMonth = date.getMonth();

function addZero(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}

function formatDateToString(d){
    var month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1);
    var day = '' + d.getDate();
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var hour = d.getHours();
    var minute = d.getMinutes();
    var second = d.getSeconds();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
    hour = addZero(hour);
    minute = addZero(minute);
 second = addZero(second);
 
 var date = [day, month, year].join('/');
 var time = [hour, minute, second].join(':');
 
 var newDate = date + " " + time;
 return newDate;
}

function setTimeForDate(date){
 date.setHours(12);
 date.setMinutes(0);
 date.setSeconds(0);
 return date;
}

function calculateDate(date, month){
 date.setMonth(month);
 date = setTimeForDate(date);
 return date;
}

function calculateLastDayMonth(date, day){
 var month = date.getMonth()+1;
 var year = date.getFullYear();
 var d = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
 if(day >= d){
  date = new Date(year, month, 0);
 }
 date = setTimeForDate(date);
 return date;
}

function returnFormattedDate(startDate, additionalMonth){
 var day = startDate.getDate();
 var newDate = calculateDate(startDate, additionalMonth);
 var correctDate = calculateLastDayMonth(newDate, day);
 return formatDateToString(correctDate);
}

$(".returnedDate").text("START DATE: " + returnFormattedDate(date, additionalMonth));

for(var x = 0; x <= 5; x++){
  $("body").append(returnFormattedDate(date, additionalMonth) + "<br>");
  additionalMonth++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5 class="returnedDate"></h5>
```